# ckeditor implementation in react-native

Tags: react-native, ckeditor

I want to implement CKEditor in a react-native mobile app but I am unable to find an appropriate package. I tried below but this is 2 years ago package as other too.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview-ckeditor

but result is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AvLO.jpg).

react-native v. 0.63.

Please help in getting rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

https://github.com/vitalyliber/react-native-ckeditor

React Native CKEditor component with no native code for React Native apps built using WebView

Comment: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager. Having errors

Comment: After resolving all bugs, I set the value some value but nothing is displaying there. and console having  message like Webview loaded, 
WebViewEditor: sending message `my message then`

but nothing is displaying

Comment: Complete code is here: https://github.com/vitalyliber/react-native-ckeditor/issues/5#issuecomment-725303596